# Bitmap manipulation in Windows Phone: How to deal with GetPixel, SetPixel, PixelFormat, etc?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

im trying to convert one of fully functional desktop apps to a Windows phone app, i was managed to convert most of the things..but one function is not working due to some syntax error.anyone know replacements for

**GetPixel,
FromArgb,
SetPixel,
MemoryStream,
Marshal,
ImageLockMode,
PixelFormat**

the code is this

```
private void tresh()
    {
        int hight = image1.Source.Height;
        int width = image1.Source.Width;
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(image1.Source);
        BitmapImage newImg = new BitmapImage(width, hight);
        int threshold = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < hight; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {

                int grayScale = (int)((img.GetPixel(j, i).R * 0.3) + (img.GetPixel(j, i).G * 0.59) + (img.GetPixel(j, i).B * 0.11));
                Color nc = Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
                newImg.SetPixel(j, i, nc);

            }
        }

        image1.Source = newImg;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        newImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();

        threshold = getOtsuNumber(bmpBytes);





        byte[] newBytArr = new byte[bmpBytes.Length];




        for (int i = 0; i < bmpBytes.Length; i++)
        {


            if ((0xFF & bmpBytes[i]) >= threshold)
            {
                newBytArr[i] = ((byte)255);

            }
            else
            {
                newBytArr[i] = ((byte)0);
            }
        }


        BitmapImage oldBmp = newImg;
        width = oldBmp.Width;
        int height = oldBmp.Height;
        BitmapData oldData = oldBmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, oldBmp.Width, oldBmp.Height),
                        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                        oldBmp.PixelFormat);
        int length = oldData.Stride * oldBmp.Height;
        byte[] stream = new byte[length];
        Marshal.Copy(oldData.Scan0, stream, 0, length);
        oldBmp.UnlockBits(oldData);


        BitmapImage bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, oldBmp.PixelFormat);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                bmp.PixelFormat);


        for (int n = 0; n < length; n++)
        {
            if ((0xFF & stream[n]) >= 57)
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(bmpData.Scan0, n, ((byte)255));

            }
            else
            {
                Marshal.WriteByte(bmpData.Scan0, n, ((byte)0));
            }

        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        image1.Source = bmp;


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to change the type `int` into `byte`

Answer (score 0):

By using this [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) GetPixel and SetPixel method extensions can be used